# How to remove white spaces in XML Document in C#

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

could anyone please help me on how to remove all the white spaces between XML tags as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

To:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>
```

Thank you heaps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use XLinq:

```
XElement.Parse(str).ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting)
```

Comment: I'm finding that it's stripping the "<?xml version="1.0"?>" from the output.

Comment: @midspace: Use `XDocument.Parse()`